# How do I manage report paging in HTML?

Tags: asp.net

I have a small, custom crafted HTML report, not using any reporting engine, for various reasons.  The client's layout is quite handy, as each report section fits on its own page, so I have one div for each page, with a CSS class of `.page`, setting A4 dimensions with margin, and a header image.  Each 'page' also has a small header table just under the header image, and a section heading label.

Now, some sections threaten to overflow their page, and I'm looking at ways to handle this.  One clumsy approach is to include a second page for those sections that might overflow, and delete these pages before rendering if they are empty.  If I do this, how can I 'tell' content on one page to overflow into the next page?

The report is finished and a once off effort, so I'm not keen to convert it into a SSRS or Telerik report just to achieve this paging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many jQuery based plugins that can add pagination and sorting etc. to a standard HTML table. Have a look at [15 Great jQuery Plugins For Better Table Manipulation](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-great-jquery-plugins-for-better-table-manipulation/). I'd personaly recommend http://www.datatables.net/ as it's very flexible and powerful.